# Can't change a specific element from a array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that changes the name of the user checking it on a array of objects.
The code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < state.users.length; i++){
      if (state.users[i].id == id) {
        state.users[i].email = change;
        console.log(state.users[i].email)
      }
    }
```

The value of `state.users[i]` does not get any change with "=". How can I change it?

The state code:

```
  state: {
    users: [
    {id: 1, name : "test", password : "test" , email : 'test@test.com', admin : false},
    {id: 2, name : "Pol", password: "PolProva", email : 'Pol@test.com', admin : true},
    {id: 3, name : "Marta", password : "MartaProva", email : 'Marta@test.com', admin : true}
    ],
    userLogged : false
  },
```

How i do get it:

```
import {f7, useStore } from 'framework7-vue';
import localforage from 'localforage'; 

    export default {
        setup(){
            const users = useStore('getUsers');
            /*const editGeneral = (id, change, toChange) => f7.store.dispatch('editName', {id : id, change : change, toChange : toChange}); */
            const testChange = (id, change) => f7.store.dispatch('testChange', {id : id, change : change})
            return{
                users,
                /*editGeneral,*/
                testChange
            };
        },
     }
```

Comment: And how do you use state?

Comment: [Should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/nm7yejLb/). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: im using Framework7 store soo i basicaly importing it and directly saving it on a date variable

Comment: @Pchaozz Please add ([edit]) all relevant information to your question and not in the comments.

Comment: @ivar sorry i just used a few times stackoverflow, im fixing it

Comment: You will need to use a reducer and will have to create a new object as Redux works on immutable objects. Try `state.users.map((user) => user.id === id ? { ...user, email: change} : user)`

Comment: @Rajesh sadly it gives me the same result

Answer (score 0):

The state is immutable, so you can't change direct like that.
If you are using React, use setState or useState hook to update it.
Else, use destructuring to update it.

Answer (score 0):

aftere update `return` it.

```js
let state = {
  users: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "test",
      password: "test",
      email: 'test@test.com',
      admin: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Pol",
      password: "PolProva",
      email: 'Pol@test.com',
      admin: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Marta",
      password: "MartaProva",
      email: 'Marta@test.com',
      admin: true
    }
  ],
  userLogged: false
}

let myId = 3
let myKey = 'email'
let myValue = 'newName_@gmail.com'

let data = state.users.map((obj) => {
  if (obj.id == myId) {
    obj[myKey] = myValue
  }
  return obj
})
console.log(data)
```